# Parse and manipulate data in tables

Tags: python, parsing

I want to automate data entry for my gilrfirend and am trying to learn to coding at at the same time. I need to extract the data from the table in this [page](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q1IVcJQnJ61LpmHkhwP9QXT05TcdhXAe) in the column "Diagnosis Codes" then strip the "IDC-9:" text, commas and then formats it into a single column which can be inserted into a spread sheet that looks up the codes and returns their meaning.

I have created a python script that edits the text from the column when copied to the clipboard.

```
import shelve, pyperclip, sys, re

mystring=pyperclip.paste()
s=mystring.replace('ICD-9:',' ').replace(',', ' ')
s=s.split()
s=' '.join(s)
s=s.replace(' ', '\n')
pyperclip.copy(s)
```

I am not sure that python is the best way of doing this. she does not use python there fore still need a way for her to use it once I figure it out.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since you haven't provided the surrounding context of this program (where is the data coming from?  where is it being placed?), it is not clear what you are sharing here.  Is this a working program that you are looking improve?  Does it have a problem or error you are trying to fix?  Or just your attempt so far that doesn't work?

Comment: You need to extract the text inside the span? `<span style="font-weight: bold;">S91001D</span>`

Comment: @HymnsForDisco the context of this program is I am trying make life easier for girl friends workflow.  I don't know the best way but I know the way they are doing it now is definitely not the best.  The data is coming from a medical billing website.  The problem I am trying to solve is manipulating the data int the "Diagnosis Codes" column into a single column of text that can be inserted into an existing spreadsheet that looks up the codes with and returns an explanation. I do not have a programming background so I am starting from scratch.

Comment: problem 1. get data into a program to manipulate it. I figured out how to do this from the clipboard with pyperclip. kind of impressed with myself.  problems is  I can't just select the column from the website.  I can save the whole table to a speadsheet then select the column and manipulate.  this works but could be better. hence my post here.  the ultimate problem will be how do I make this time saving script into something that she can use.  she doesn't run python scripts at all especially on her work computer.

Comment: @PedroLobito I need to extract all of the data in the column with the exception of "ICD-9:"

Comment: Sorry I actually missed the "this page" link on first read.  Just a thought, it seems that page contains (potentially) sensitive information, and probably shouldn't be shared like this without the consent of parties involved.  And either way, it wasn't necessary to share all that, it would be preferred to give a stripped / simplified version of the page

Comment: You can automate website interaction with `selenium`, or directly extract values from a websites plain HTML response with `beautifulsoup`.  This destination "spreadsheet" is important to define however.  Is the spreadsheet accessed through another website?  The same website?  Another GUI program on the local machine?  Is it stored in an Excel file (or similar) that you could access directly to extract the data, or does the "explanation" need to be viewed via another UI program?

Comment: The destination spreadsheet is a excel lookup table which provides the explanation of the billing codes. it is stored locally.  I am sure the functions of this could be incorporated into this application in the future but is beyond my current skill level. Currently I am trying to figure out how to extract the necessary data and then input into the existing spread sheet. Ultimately I will need to figure out how to make this into a tool that can be used by others.

Comment: @splattman_g for extracting data from the webpage, selenium is probably a good place to start.  You can use it to load the page, search for DOM elements, and get their text.  Selenium has bindings for python that you can install